# Copy a file block per block in C

Tags: c, file, copy, block

I'm trying to divide a file into an x ammount of blocks of size y (in bytes), so that I can copy each block individually. How can I do that?

Comment: find out the total size of the file, divide it into the appropriate number of blocks and using `fseek()` & perhaps `ftell()`, do the copying. Post some code and we can provide you with helpers...

Comment: Well, to a FAT virtual file system that I created. To put files in it, I need to break them down into blocks of the same size as the blocks in my file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [fread](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fread/)

```
char buffer[ysize];
fread(buffer, ysize, 1, fp);
```

Each time you read ysize bytes in buffer from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Some struct stat structures have additional members in them that prove useful when copying files:

```
     st_blksize  The optimal I/O block size for the file.

     st_blocks   The actual number of blocks allocated for the file in
                 (check local system).
```

If the block size you read is an even multiple of st_blksize you tend to get more efficient reading of the file.

```
   size_t   desiredSize = 1E4;                // largest buffer size to read into
   size_t   blocks = desiredSize / st.st_blksize;
   if ( blocks < 1 )              // fail safe test
       blocks = 1;
   size_t   true_size = blocks * st.st_blksize;     // this is the size to read
   char *buffer = malloc(true_size);
```

Failing st_blksize, <stdio.h> provides a BUFSIZ macro for buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = fopen ( "x" , "rb");
if (x==NULL) {perror("file could not be opened"); exit(1);}

y = fopen ( "y" , "wb");
if (x==NULL) {perror("file could not be opened"); exit(1);}

char* buf = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*1024); //1024 is buffer size
```

To read 1024 chars into the buffer:

```
fread(buf, sizeof(char), 1024, x);
```

You do the rest.