# Storage manager function to implement read operations on a file

Tags: file, storage, fread, filehandle, fseek

How to adapt my program to perform the following operations:

1.To read first block of a file
2.To read current block of a file
3.To read previous block of a file
4.To read next block of a file
5.To read last block of a file
 The following is the code written by me to read a data file using a file pointer and I want to implement the above operations

```
void main()
{ 
 FILE *fptr;
 char filename[15];
 char ch;

 printf("Enter the filename to be opened \n");
 scanf("%s", filename);
 /*  open the file for reading */
 fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
 if (fptr == NULL)
 {
   printf("Cannot open file \n");
   exit(0);
 }
 ch = fgetc(fptr);
 while (ch != EOF)
 {
  printf ("%c", ch);
  ch = fgetc(fptr);
 }
  fclose(fptr);
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: How would you define a 'block' here?

Comment: Block can be defined as a page in a file handler wherein by using file pointers you can traverse through the page files by setting a currentpos field

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162421/copy-a-file-block-per-block-in-c